# Rama inexistente git flow, sólo yo la tengo

Tags: git

Tengo un conflicto con git flow, es la primera vez que lo utilizo, inicialicé mal, así quedó:

```
Branch name for production releases: [develop]
Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
Branch name for "next release" development: [roles]
```

realicé cambios y los subí pero no se encuentran en ninguna parte del repositorio, les agradecería mucho [image: asi está mi git log]

Comment: puedes ver los cambios en tu entorno local? entonces quiere decir que los tienes guardados de manera local pero no donde tengas el repositorio, dicho de otra manera, puedes ver el push que has hecho? si no es asi ese es tu problema, si es asi, probablemente te hayan desaparecido los cambios por un bad merge

Comment: No puedo verlos, entonces es local, voy a intentar solucionarlo, muchas gracias por responder!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push, tiene pinta de que el commit ha sido local solo, me suele pasar mucho